# How to add 'SELECT' option in drop down list struts 2

Tags: java, struts2

I have a list of *Bottles* objects from action and I am successfully displaying in the drop down list like this :

```
<s:select name="bottle.fileName" multiple="false" list="bottles" listKey="fileName" listValue="displayName" />
```

Here list of bottle are coming fine. But I want to display the 'SELECT' option as first value in the drop down list.
How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Refer this Link](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sselect-drop-down-box-example/)
I think this answer will be helpful for you.

As mentioned in sree's comment:

> headerKey and headerValue is the answer
>
> ```
> <s:select headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Bottle" name="bottle.fileName" multiple="false" list="bottles"   
>           listKey="fileName"    listValue="displayName" />
> ```

Comment: Thanks Saba Pathy
headerKey and headerValue is the answer

        <s:select headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Bottle" name="bottle.fileName" multiple="false" list="bottles"    listKey="fileName"    listValue="displayName" />

Comment: oh yeah. Welcome sree.